# Changing the Title of a Blog

Tags: configuration

How can I change the title of my blog? It's found on the main page of the blog above the previews of the posts. I am attaching a screen shot.

I want to change "The Scrapbooked Bible Study" (on the left above the first blog post preview) to "Winning the Victory." Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page seems to be a Views page, but there is no way of telling from the screenshot if you're using a special module to build those page or simply Views.

If it's Views then you can Edit the particular View, it has the `Title` option for the Page, that's where you change it.

You can find list of all Views under Structure on the top menu.

Comment: Yep, looks like a Views page. http://lighthousebiblestudies.com/katy-kauffman-blog

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment! "Views" is what I couldn't think of.